# JD-Eclipse: How do I attach source to .class file for my own .java file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jd-eclipse

I have the JD-Eclipse plugin installed and all File associations set properly and as default.  The JD-Eclipse editor comes up when I click om the .class file but it complains that it has no source attached.

Note: I am trying to look at the decompiled java for a .java file that I wrote in my project.

my source files are in the project src/ subdirectory
my .class output files are project bin/ subdirectory

Here is the contents of the project .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-11">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Here are my screen captures of my related settings

[General>Content Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOJDI.png)

[File Associations>.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLOXx.png)

[File Associations>.class without source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGLOo.png)

[open .class file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxu7c.png)

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the JD-Eclipse "editor" that's been opened? Right-click and check the "Open With..." menu.

Comment: @nitind  Yes , it has the little coffee mug icon in the window tab (instead of J101 icon). I also tried "Open With...JD Class File Viewer" just now and it's the same issue.

Comment: @nitind There is also a setting under 
Window > preferences ... General > Content Types. 
Content type: Java Class File,
File Associations: *.class (with a lock symbol),
Associated Editor: Standard Java Class Viewer

Comment: @nitind I added screen captures to my original question